# Navigation bar is not shown properly when get back from Movie Player in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app, I load a HTML Page in Web View which contains a video. Till this the navigation bar is shown properly.

But when i play video with by default Movie Player in iphone & try to see it in Both Landscape/Portrait mode with Full Screen. **When get Back from Movie Player, the Navigation Bar is go to upside & status Bar is Cover some view**.[image]

I am not taken mediaPlayer framework or any other class in my project.

**How can i solved This issue??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just paste this below line in to the `viewWillAppear:` on that view controller class where this issue occurs.

**Objective C**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

**Swift**

```
UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(false, with:UIStatusBarAnimation.none)
```

Comment: but i am taken any movie player class or media player framework in my project

Comment: @user1673099 but just add this line in your that class where you back from the moviewplayer dude.. so it set the control with +20 point with statusbar dude..

Comment: dude just try to make it in your code where moviecontroller dissappear and your current view display.. it just an logic dude... so :)

Comment: I don't know where moviecontroller is dissappear and i also put breakPoints on webview (get back from Moviecontroller) but viewDidLoad & ViewWillAppear methods are not called

Comment: so how to take movie player class in project??

Comment: try this somewhere.. self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame, 0.0, 0.0);

Comment: Thanks . you saved my life.
This is swift version 
 UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(false, with:UIStatusBarAnimation.none )

Comment: @Majid, Welcome and also Thanks. I've added Swift code solution as I added the Objective C solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Movie player class replace

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Means if you hide your status bar when came back from player then the height of the view will increased by 20 pixels.
So your view will go upside

Comment: I don't get any Movie Player class in my project. I am only take web view in which i load HTML page.

Comment: You are not hiding status bar anywhere.Right?